# JOGAMP simple triangle isn't getting displayed on screen

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to get a triangle to display in a window. I get the window to appear, but the window is black and no triangle appears in the window. The shader files are able to be opened (if they weren't, I would get a FileNotFoundException), however the triangle does not get displayed onto the screen. Here is the code that I have:

```java
public class GoodbyeSimpleWorld implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {

    private static GLWindow window;
    private static Animator animator;

    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    int shaderProgram;
    IntBuffer VAO;
    IntBuffer VBO;
    int iVBO, iVAO;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GoodbyeSimpleWorld().setup();
    }

    private void setup() {

        GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
        GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);

        window = GLWindow.create(glCapabilities);

        window.setTitle("Goodbye Simple World");
        window.setSize(1024, 768);

        window.addGLEventListener(this);
        window.addKeyListener(this);

        window.setVisible(true);

        window.addGLEventListener(this);
        window.addKeyListener(this);

        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowDestroyed(WindowEvent e) {
                animator.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        animator = new Animator();
        animator.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();

        ShaderCode vertexShader = ShaderCode.create(gl, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, this.getClass(),
                "shaders/gl3", null, "goodbye", "vert", null, true);
        vertexShader.compile(gl);

        ShaderCode fragmentShader = ShaderCode.create(gl, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, this.getClass(),
                "shaders/gl3", null, "goodbye", "frag", null, true);
        fragmentShader.compile(gl);

        shaderProgram = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader.id());
        gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader.id());
        gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertexShader.id());
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader.id());
        VBO = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
        VAO = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);

        gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, VAO);
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, VBO);

        iVBO = VBO.get();
        iVAO = VAO.get();

        gl.glBindVertexArray(iVAO);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
        gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.length, FloatBuffer.wrap(vertices), gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.BYTES, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
        drawable.setAutoSwapBufferMode(true);
        gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(iVAO);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(iVAO);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

- `VBO` is a buffer containing the *name* of the VBO, but you pass it to `glBufferData` where the *data* you want to store in the VBO is expected, you never copy the `vertices` array into the buffer
- you call `glVertexAttribPointer` with `Long.MIN_VALUE`, which is around -2^63, but the value you should put there is `0`
- you do not have a VAO bound when you do the actual draw call
- You never have a `SwapBuffers` call anywhere. Note that GLEventListener can be set to `setAutoSwapBufferMode` mode to do that for you but this on ly affects the `dispay` method, having your draw call in `init` does not make much sense.

Comment: I made most of the changes that you suggested to me and I believe that I might have missed something because I am still having difficulty getting the triangle to display.

Comment: YOu still have no VAO bound for the draw call

Comment: How do I add a VAO bound for the draw call?

Comment: `glBindVertexArray()`. But you really should learn about the basic workings of OpenGL first, stackoverflow isn't a tutorial site, but lots of good GL tutorials do exist.

Comment: I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle . I am pulling source code from here: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp and trying to convert it to Java.

Comment: Also I added iVAO and iVBO which are the int values from the int buffer. I also added a VAO bound on both sides of the draw call and I am still having trouble. Was I supposed to insert it a different way?

Comment: @amicharski Rather use our official examples using JOGL: https://gist.github.com/xranby/ccbcfcaef341f5bd1ba8 Another contributor already ported similar examples to JOGL: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Jogl_Tutorial